# Energy efficiency in modern houses

Tags: energy

What is an energy efficient way of heating modern houses in a winter scenario and how could we experiment it? For example, my group tried heating a beaker of water with a hot plate, microwave,and an oven to show the heat conduction through heat conduction, convection, and radiation. So what will be another way to experiment the heating of the house?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure this is really about physics. Energy efficiency is mostly about engineering.

Comment: The earth heat energy.

Comment: I'm not sure this is really a question about physics. Have a [Google for heat pump](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=heat%20pump) and you should find useful info.